# How to focus an already opened but not focused tab in Service Console?

Tags: service-cloud-console, javascript-controller, salesforce-classic

I would like to open a tab of a Contact in a Service Console:

```
sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, CONTACT_ID, true);
```

I can't make it though when it's already opened. I receive an error in browser's console:

```
openPrimaryTab: Opening a duplicate tab is not allowed.
```

I know I can focus the tab having its `Id` but I don't always have it -
 sometimes there are some tabs opened from previous sessions or I opened one manually.

I thought that I maybe could somehow distinguish already opened tabs but I looked through a [Salesforce Console Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_methods_tabs.htm) and I didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's a way to do that. I used [`getPrimaryTabIds()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_getprimarytabids.htm) to get an array of tabs' ids and then [`getPageInfo()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_getpageinfo.htm) to extract an information from the tab. If it's a tab of an object, a `pageInfo` field contains an `objectId` field with an `Id` of the viewed object. Then I simply compare every tab object's `Id` with an `Id` of the one I want to be opened:

```
var sid = MY_OBJECT_ID;
sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, "/" + sid, true, undefined, function(response) {
    if (!response.success) {
        sforce.console.getPrimaryTabIds(function(response) {
            var primaryTabIds = response.ids;
            for (let id of primaryTabIds) {
                sforce.console.getPageInfo(id, function(response) {
                    var myVar = JSON.parse(response.pageInfo);
                    var objectId = myVar.objectId;
                    if (objectId === sid) {
                        sforce.console.focusPrimaryTabById(id);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

But I still hope there's a better answer.

Comment: check my answer it will help you

Answer (score 1):

This small piece of code perfectly works for me.

Rather than first argument as `null`, I have used `undefined`.
secondly, use `tabName` parameter and make this tabName as unique.
And then based on tabname it will focus on Primary tab.

call this `callOpenPrimaryTab` function either from button click or URL.

```
function callOpenPrimaryTab(contactId,contactName) 
{ 
    if(sforce.console.isInConsole())
    {            
        sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(undefined,"/"+contactId, true, contactName, openSuccess,contactId+contactName);
        sforce.console.focusPrimaryTabByName(contactId+contactName, focusSuccess);
    } 

}
var openSuccess = function openSuccess(result) {
    //Report whether opening the new tab was successful
    if (result.success == true) {
        //alert('Primary tab successfully opened');
    } else {
        //alert('Primary tab cannot be opened');
    }
};
```

Comment: What in a situation when I've already opened tab manually? In a console I receive ``focusPrimaryTabByName: Invalid Name: 0030E00000HQvF1QALCONTACT NAME``  ``openPrimaryTab: Opening a duplicate tab is not allowed.``