Focus on new tab doesn't work sforce.console.openPrimaryTab
We are using sforce.console.openPrimaryTab method from aura to open new tab and redirect user there:
sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, "/lightning/r/Opportunity/" + t + "/view", true, "Opportunity"))

We set Active = TRUE and in most of the cases it works. But for one particular user new tab opens, but focus doesn't work
Is there any browser versions or settings that can prevent it?

Similar issues were reported earlier, pasting one here which have comprehensive answers, code references.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/208735/how-to-focus-an-already-opened-but-not-focused-tab-in-service-console
Hope it helps.
